# Python multiprocessing pool not chunking properly

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with: I have a python class with an instance method which takes in a list of strings and computes a result for each string, ultimately combining the results before returning, like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def do_task(stringList):
        for s in stringList:
            result = computeResult(s)
        # combine results below...
```

Since the computations with the strings are all independent (and rather expensive), I'm trying to parallelize the operation with the Pool class in the multiprocessing module. I've thus defined a parallel version of `do_task` as follows (I'm currently just printing the separate results instead of combining them):

```
def do_task_parallel(stringList):
    numProcs = 2
    pool = Pool(processes=numProcs)
    chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(stringList) / float(numProcs)))
    for result in pool.imap(self.do_task, stringList, chunksize):
        print result
    pool.close()
```

According to my understanding of how Pool works based on documentation and examples I've read, this should split my stringList iterable into chunks roughly of size chunkSize, each of which is submitted as a task to one of the processes in the pool. Thus, if I have a list `stringList = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"]` split up amongst 2 processes (giving a chunksize of 2), pool should divide this up into `stringList1 = ["foo1", "foo2"]` and `stringList2 = ["foo3", "foo4"]`, which will be handled by the two different processes in parallel.

However, when I create a Foo() object and call `foo.do_task_parallel(stringList)`, it seems that pool is passing each element of my `stringList` separately to `do_task` (as a chunk of one). Not only does this not speed up my code, but it makes it incorrect and actually slows it down, as `do_task` then calls `computeResult` on each character of the one input string passed in on each of the four separate calls. I was expecting two calls with each call handling an input list of size 2, not four calls handling a single input string. I've checked and `chunksize` is indeed 2. What am I doing wrong? If it helps, I'm running python 2.7.3 on Windows 7 through cygwin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is off ;-)  `chunksize` is purely an optional optimization:  it changes *nothing* about what's passed to the worker functions, it only gives a hint to the `multiprocessing` machinery about how many tasks to send over the internal inter-process pipes at a time.

If you want your worker function to be passed a list of strings, then you have to explicitly code that.  For example, and sticking it on multiple lines for clarity:

```
chunks = [stringList[i: i+chunksize]
          for i in xrange(0, len(stringList), chunksize)]

for result in pool.imap(self.do_task, chunks):
    print result
```

Answer (score 2):

`Pool.map` and `Pool.imap` are designed to behave equivalently to the built-in Python function `map` (except parallel). As such, they apply the function you give them individually to each item in the input.

`chunksize` deals with how items are blocked out to *multiprocessing tasks*, but doesn't affect how the function is called on the individual items. (Essentially, for map/imap the task handler already has a `for item in input: ...` built in.)

Seems like what you'd really want to do here is map out the `computeResult` calls via parallel map, and then do the combining after the results have been acquired.